# How do you find the time difference between onStop and onCreate lifecycle callbacks?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am an absolute beginner and was trying to code a Count-up-timer app that will run in the background, in other words when the app is closed from overview or when the back button is pressed, the timer will still appear to continue on the corrected time the next time the app is opened. I tried to do this by using SharedPreferences.

An error that I run into is that when I launch the emulator, the timer does not start at 00:00:00 as it should, however, it starts at random times. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yXPW.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView timerText;
TextView dayText;
Button startStopButton;

Timer timer;
TimerTask timertask;
Double time = 0.0;
Double mEndTime = 0.0;
Double startingSysTime = 0.0;
Double timeGap = 0.0;

public static final String SHARED_PREFS ="sharedPrefs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
    startStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startStopButton);
    dayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dayText);
    timer = new Timer();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    time = Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong("mTimeValue", Double.doubleToLongBits(0.0)));
    mEndTime = Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong("onDestr_SysTime", Double.doubleToLongBits(0.0)));
    if(mEndTime==0.0){
        startingSysTime = 0.0;
    }else{
        startingSysTime = (double) (System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    timeGap = startingSysTime - mEndTime;
    time += timeGap;
    startTimer();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i("TIMEGAP", "onStop called");
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("mTimeValue", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(time)); //saves the time value
    editor.putLong("onDestr_SysTime", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(System.currentTimeMillis())); //saves the CurrentSystemTime when onStop is invoked
    editor.apply();
}

private void startTimer() {
    timertask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    time++;
                    timerText.setText(getTimerText());
                    dayText.setText(getDayText());
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0, 1000);
} 

private String getDayText() {
        int rounded = (int) Math.round(time);
        int days = (rounded / 86400);

        return formatDay(days);
    }

private String formatDay(int days) {
    String pluralDays;
    if (days == 1) {
        pluralDays = " Day";
    } else {
        pluralDays = " Days";
    }
    return days + pluralDays;
}


private String getTimerText() {
    int rounded = (int) Math.round(time);

    int seconds = ((rounded % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    int minutes = ((rounded % 86400) % 3600) / 60;
    int hours = ((rounded % 86400) / 3600);

    return formatTime(seconds, minutes, hours);
}

private String formatTime(int seconds, int minutes, int hours) {
    return String.format("%02d", hours) + " : " + String.format("%02d", minutes) + " : " + String.format("%02d", seconds);
}
```

EDIT: Problem fixed, I simply had to convert `timeGap` to seconds by dividing it by 1000

```
timeGap = (startingSysTime - mEndTime)/1000;
```

Comment: did `onStop` trigger?

Comment: Yes, it did i when i pressed the back button and closed the app using overview. It showed up in the log (i had a log.d in the onStop code block) and so I am sure that onStop triggered

Comment: Do you need it to run accurately through a phone shutdown and reboot?

Comment: Yes, it would be preferable to have it still run accurately through a reboot, is this possible without the use of any services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable{
     
      //Todo write your code here
      handler.postdelayed(this,1000);

  },1000);

Start where you need

long starttime;
   start time = System.currentTimeMilisecond();


End where you need

 long currtime = System.currentTimeMilisecond() - startime;

}
```

According to your question try to convert this millisecond in your format which you need. Store long value in shared preference if you want to manage this on app close also

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I fixed my problem simply by editing this line  `timeGap = (startingSysTime - mEndTime)/1000;`